# Outlook information from selected contactitem

Tags: c#, winforms, outlook, selecteditem, contactitem

I am trying to get Information of the selected ContactItem in Outlook 2010. Such data as: "Name, CompanyName, Adress" etc. pp.

I need this Information to be loaded into my WinForm and be shown as TEXT in a couple of Labels on the Form. The Wordprocess is as follows: Right Click on wished Contact in Outlook > Click on the ContextMenu (AddIn) I created.

Comment: [what have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)

Comment: I've tried by getting Information from the contact via "Outlook.Explorer" ,... yet I am not getting things right, whilst trying this out. Ergo I need help on how to adress the selected item

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example that should give you the [`ContactItem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.contactitem_members.aspx) reference from the [`Explorer.Selection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff861267.aspx). You can then access all the `ContactItem` properties from the current active selection. If you want to support multiple `ContactItems` selected, you would have to change the behavior slightly.

```
Outlook.Selection selection = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveExplorer().Selection;
if (selection.OfType<Outlook.ContactItem>().Count() == 1) // only support single item selection
{
  Outlook.ContactItem contact = selection.OfType<Outlook.ContactItem>().FirstOrDefault();
  string name = contact.FullName;
  string company = contact.CompanyName;
  string address = contact.BusinessAddress;
}
```